# intel-virtual-output freezes

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I have been successfully running a triple-monitor setup with my ThinkPad W530.

Suddenly at some point within the last days the command stopped working though and freezes.
I would activate the monitor(s) using the `thinkdisp` indicator (roughly equivalent to running `modprobe bbswitch` and `optirun true`) and then run `intel-virtual-output`. The monitor(s) would show the background picture, but I couldn't do anything anymore but moving the mouse around.

Checking from tty1 I could see that `intel-virtual-output` was indeed still running, killing it didn't change anything, only killing the additional `Xorg` turned off the external monitor(s) but did not bring back my built in screen to be responsive.

The last update to the package (according to Synaptic history) was

```
xserver-xorg-video-intel (2:2.99.917+git20150128.2e7ae760-0ubuntu0sarvatt~utopic) 
                       to 2:2.99.917+git20150131.dac01d08-0ubuntu0sarvatt~utopic
```

but that's already several weeks ago and I'm quite sure it's been working since.
I stopped compiling it from source since it seemed to  be included in the package now.

I use `nvidia-340` from `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` (346 wouldn't work the last time I tried).

Some excerpets from Xorg.8.log (trying with only one external monitor):

```
[ 12307.179] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[ 12307.179] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 12307.179] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 12307.179] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"  
[ 12307.180] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[ 12307.180] (**) |   |-->Device "DiscreteNvidia"
[ 12307.180] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.

(...)

[ 12307.184] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia-340/xorg/libglx.so
[ 12307.198] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[ 12307.198]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[ 12307.198]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[ 12307.198] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  340.76  Thu Jan 22 11:24:42 PST 2015
[ 12307.198] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[ 12307.199] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia-340/xorg/nvidia_drv.so

(...)

[ 12307.201] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[ 12307.201] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[ 12307.201] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[ 12307.201] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[ 12307.201] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[ 12307.201] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "NoLogo" "true"
[ 12307.201] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"
[ 12307.201] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[ 12309.189] (II) NVIDIA(0): Display (BenQ GL2450H (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[ 12309.189] (II) NVIDIA(0):     Vision stereo.
[ 12309.189] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Found DRM driver nvidia-drm (20150116)
[ 12309.191] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU Quadro K1000M (GK107GL) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[ 12309.191] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[ 12309.191] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 80.07.33.00.0f
[ 12309.191] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on Quadro K1000M at PCI:1:0:0
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0):     BenQ GL2450H (DFP-1) (boot, connected)
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-5
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-6
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: Internal LVDS
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0): BenQ GL2450H (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ GL2450H (DFP-1): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 480.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-6: Internal DisplayPort
[ 12309.196] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 480.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 12309.196] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[ 12309.196] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device BenQ GL2450H (DFP-1) (Using EDID frequencies has
[ 12309.196] (**) NVIDIA(0):     been enabled on all display devices.)
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID for BenQ GL2450H (DFP-1) contradicts itself: mode
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     "1920x1080" is specified in the EDID; however, the EDID's
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     valid HorizSync range (30.000-83.000 kHz) would exclude
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     this mode's HorizSync (28.1 kHz); ignoring HorizSync check
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     for mode "1920x1080".
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID for BenQ GL2450H (DFP-1) contradicts itself: mode
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     "720x480" is specified in the EDID; however, the EDID's
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     valid HorizSync range (30.000-83.000 kHz) would exclude
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     this mode's HorizSync (15.7 kHz); ignoring HorizSync check
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     for mode "720x480".
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID for BenQ GL2450H (DFP-1) contradicts itself: mode
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     "720x480" is specified in the EDID; however, the EDID's
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     valid HorizSync range (30.000-83.000 kHz) would exclude
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     this mode's HorizSync (15.7 kHz); ignoring HorizSync check
[ 12309.198] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     for mode "720x480".
[ 12309.199] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID for BenQ GL2450H (DFP-1) contradicts itself: mode
[ 12309.199] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     "720x576" is specified in the EDID; however, the EDID's
[ 12309.199] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     valid HorizSync range (30.000-83.000 kHz) would exclude
[ 12309.199] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     this mode's HorizSync (15.6 kHz); ignoring HorizSync check
[ 12309.199] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     for mode "720x576".
[ 12309.199] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID for BenQ GL2450H (DFP-1) contradicts itself: mode
[ 12309.199] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     "720x576" is specified in the EDID; however, the EDID's
[ 12309.199] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     valid HorizSync range (30.000-83.000 kHz) would exclude
[ 12309.199] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     this mode's HorizSync (15.6 kHz); ignoring HorizSync check
[ 12309.199] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     for mode "720x576".
[ 12309.201] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[ 12309.201] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[ 12309.201] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[ 12309.201] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[ 12309.201] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[ 12309.201] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
[ 12309.201] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1080
[ 12309.209] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (92, 91); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[ 12309.209] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[ 12309.209] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[ 12309.209] (II) NVIDIA: Using 3072.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[ 12309.209] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[ 12309.219] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
[ 12309.281] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[ 12309.281] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[ 12309.281] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[ 12309.281] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[ 12309.281] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[ 12309.281] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[ 12309.281] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[ 12309.281] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[ 12309.281] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[ 12309.282] (--) RandR disabled
[ 12309.286] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[ 12309.287] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[ 12309.287] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.(II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have similar issue on Thinkpad Carbon x1, I manage to fix it by upgrading my kernel to 3.19.

Comment: Do you have instructions on this at hand? Haven't ever manually upgraded the kernel so hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Is relatively simple, check this out http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/02/upgrade-linux-kernel-3-19-ubuntu-14-04/, take care to use the instructions for your architecture x86 or x64. Is also recommended to purge the xorg-edgers ppa befor updating.

Comment: @Calin - I updated to 15.04 now, which is only on `3.16.0` but already made the described behavior go away; it fails with `XIO:  fatal IO error 11 Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":8" after 20 requests (20 known processed) with 0 events remaining.` now - but that's a seperate issue for sure.

Comment: Will wait for the next major release,

Comment: For reference, I filed a bug against the `IO error 11` thing on [freedesktop.org](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90211) now.